# Wget 403 error on volafile

Tags: wget, http-status-code-403

I always used wget to download files from my personal volafile room.
The problem emerged a few months ago.
Very often (but not always), when I try to download a file with wget:

```
wget -U Mozilla -o Log_err.txt -O output.file "https://volafile.io/get/LglqaCs-mtoH/test_file.txt"
```

the program can't get the file *(ERROR 403: Forbidden)*. Here is the log:

```
--2017-00-00 00:00:00--  https://volafile.io/get/LglqaCs-mtoH/test_file.txt
Resolving volafile.io (volafile.io)... 51.255.168.166
Connecting to volafile.io (volafile.io)|51.255.168.166|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://dl1.volafile.io/get/LglqaCs-mtoH/test_file.txt [following]
--2017-00-00 00:00:00--  https://dl1.volafile.io/get/LglqaCs-mtoH/test_file.txt
Resolving dl1.volafile.io (dl1.volafile.io)... 144.76.235.164
Connecting to dl1.volafile.io (dl1.volafile.io)|144.76.235.164|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /redir/get/LglqaCs-mtoH [following]
--2017-00-00 00:00:00--  https://dl1.volafile.io/redir/get/LglqaCs-mtoH
Connecting to dl1.volafile.io (dl1.volafile.io)|144.76.235.164|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-00-00 00:00:00 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

If I try to download a picture from the same room, uploaded at the same time:

```
wget -U Mozilla -o Log_yes.txt -O output.file "https://volafile.io/get/LhCL3aytoc2q/test_pic.jpg"
```

the program gets the file normally. Here is the log:

```
--2017-00-00 00:00:00--  https://volafile.io/get/LhCL3aytoc2q/test_pic.jpg
Resolving volafile.io (volafile.io)... 51.255.168.166
Connecting to volafile.io (volafile.io)|51.255.168.166|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://dl1.volafile.net/get/LhCL3aytoc2q/test_pic.jpg [following]
--2017-00-00 00:00:00--  https://dl1.volafile.net/get/LhCL3aytoc2q/test_pic.jpg
Resolving dl1.volafile.net (dl1.volafile.net)... 104.25.135.100, 104.25.136.100
Connecting to dl1.volafile.net (dl1.volafile.net)|104.25.135.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3801 (3.7K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: 'output.file'
0K ... 100%  462K=0.008s
2017-00-00 00:00:00 (462 KB/s) - 'output.file' saved [3801/3801]
```

Comparing the logs and according to my tests, it seems that if the file uploaded is actually hosted on a *volafile.net* domain, wget can download it; when the file is hosted on a *volafile.net* domain, wget can't download it.

The "user agent" option (-U) doesn't solve the problem.
The file is directly downloadable with any browser. You can try too.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a cookie (with a ridiculously obvious name):

```
Cookie: allow-download=1
```

This gives me a redirect and a 403:

```
wget 'https://dl1.volafile.io/get/LglqaCs-mtoH/test_file.txt'
```

While this works just fine:

```
wget 'https://dl1.volafile.io/get/LglqaCs-mtoH/test_file.txt' --header 'Cookie: allow-download=1'
```